# How to use alphauserpoints credits towards adsmanager payment in joomla?

Tags: php, joomla, content-management-system

Are there any plugins or hacks that let me use alphauserpoints credits towards payments for adsmanager adverts in joomla?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution for Alphauserpoints 1.7.4, Adsmanager 2.7 RC3 and PaidSystem.

Edit `components\com_paidsystem\api.paidsystem.php`

**After** `defined('_JEXEC') or die( 'Restricted access' );` add the below code

```
//AlphaUserPoints start
$api_AUP = JPATH_SITE.DS.'components'.DS.'com_alphauserpoints'.DS.'helper.php';
if ( file_exists($api_AUP))
{
    require_once ($api_AUP);            
}
//AlphaUserPoints end
```

Next you need to edit function getBalance($userid). This is in api.paidsystem.php

```
function getBalance($userid)
{
    //Alphauserpoints substitute for value
    //Get the RefferreID of a user
    $referreid = AlphaUserPointsHelper::getAnyUserReferreID((int)$userid);
    $profil=AlphaUserPointsHelper:: getUserInfo ($referreid);
    $value=$profil->points;
    //Alphauserpoints substitute for value end

    //ORIGINAL CODE BELOW
    /*$db =JFactory::getDbo();
    //$db->setQuery( "SELECT credit FROM #__paidsystem_credits WHERE    userid=".(int)$userid );
    //To explicitly convert a value to integer, use either the (int) or     (integer) casts. 
    $value = $db->loadResult();*/

    if ($value == "")
        $value = 0;
    return $value;
}
```

Then edit the next function

```
//EDIT this to debit credits from alphauserpoints
//Use alphauserpoints rule to debit from alphauserpoints.

function removeCredits($userid,$num,$description) 
{   
    $db =JFactory::getDbo();
    //$db->setQuery( "SELECT credit FROM  #__paidsystem_credits WHERE userid=".(int)$userid );
    //$balance = (float) $db->loadResult();
    $referreid = AlphaUserPointsHelper::getAnyUserReferreID((int)$userid);
    $profil=AlphaUserPointsHelper:: getUserInfo ($referreid);
    $balance=$profil->points;

    //$db->setQuery( "UPDATE #__paidsystem_credits SET credit=credit-".(float)$num." WHERE userid=".(int)$userid );
    //$db->query();
    echo "removeCredits=$userid,$num";
    $obj = new stdClass();
    $obj->userid = $userid;
    $obj->balance = $balance;
    $obj->change = $num * -1;
    $obj->description = $description;
    $obj->date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    AlphaUserPointsHelper::newpoints( 'plgaup_purchaseadvertising', '','', 'purchase advertising', $num*-1);

    $db->insertObject("#__paidsystem_history",$obj);        
}
```

**REMEMBER:** You will need to create a new rule in the administrator section of the alphauserpoints component in Joomla for this to work. In my code the new rule name was called plgaup_purchaseadvertising.